# Putting two tables together for summation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get all the data from the newsaleshistory table summed with the BWlease table? Including only lease pymts and zero newsaleshistory amts.

All I get in my output is the sum only if they have a lease amt from the BWlease table.  All other accounts are zero.

The output should be all the rev amts from the newsaleshistory table and any lease amts from the BWlease table, regardless if there is any. This would be by month and account. Also, would be inluded are any account lease amts from the BWlease table that are not in the account newsaleshistory table. Like a Union All.

I have the code listed below.

```
SELECT  top 50 [NewSalesHistory].[Region]
                ,[NewSalesHistory].[ShipTo]
                ,[Customer].[Name]
                ,[CustomerMap].[SP]
                ,[Customer].[SalesOffice]
                ,[SalesOffice].[City] + ' , ' + ' ' + [SalesOffice].[State] SOName
                ,[Customer].[SalesOffice] + '-' + [SalesOffice].[City] + ' , ' + ' ' + [SalesOffice].[State] BRLocation
                ,coalesce([CustomerMap].[SH-Y1], ' ') as 'Y1 Partner'
                ,coalesce([customer].[strat1], ' ') as 'STRAT 1'
                ,coalesce([customer].[strat3], ' ') as 'STRAT 3' 
                ,[salesoffice].[AVPName]
                ,[salesoffice].[DMName]
                ,SUBSTRING ([IndustryCode].[Description],1,3) as 'Market'
                ,[IndustryCode].[Description] as 'Industry'
                ,[newsaleshistory].[AccountType]
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '6/1/2016' and '6/30/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Jun-16]  AS 'Jun-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '7/1/2016' and '7/31/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Jul-16]  as 'Jul-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '8/1/2016' and '8/31/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Aug-16]  as 'Aug-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '9/1/2016' and '9/30/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Sep-16]  as 'Sep-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '10/1/2016' and '10/31/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Oct-16]  as 'Oct-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '11/1/2016' and '11/30/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Nov-16]  as 'Nov-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '12/1/2016' and '12/31/2016' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Dec-16]  as 'Dec-16'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '1/1/2017' and '1/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Jan-17]  as 'Jan-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '2/1/2017' and '2/28/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Feb-17]  as 'Feb-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '3/1/2017' and '3/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Mar-17]  as 'Mar-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '4/1/2017' and '4/30/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Apr-17]  as 'Apr-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '5/1/2017' and '5/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[May-17]  as 'May-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '6/1/2017' and '6/30/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Jun-17]  as 'Jun-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '7/1/2017' and '7/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Jul-17]  as 'Jul-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '8/1/2017' and '8/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Aug-17]  as 'Aug-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '9/1/2017' and '9/30/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Sep-17]  as 'Sep-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '10/1/2017' and '10/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Oct-17]  as 'Oct-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '11/1/2017' and '11/30/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Nov-17]  as 'Nov-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '12/1/2017' and '12/31/2017' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Dec-17]  as 'Dec-17'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '1/1/2018' and '1/31/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Jan-18]  as 'Jan-18'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '2/1/2018' and '2/28/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Feb-18]  as 'Feb-18'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '3/1/2018' and '3/31/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Mar-18]  as 'Mar-18'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '4/1/2018' and '4/30/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[Apr-18]  as 'Apr-18'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '5/1/2018' and '5/31/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[May-18]  as 'May-18'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '6/1/2016' and '5/31/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[24 Month]  as '24 Month'
                ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '6/1/2017' and '5/31/2018' then newbillingdata else 0 end ) + [X].[12 Month]  as '12 Month'
      FROM [NewSalesHistory]
      left  join [Customer] on [newsaleshistory].[ShipTo] = [customer].[customer]
      left  join [SalesOffice] on [Customer].[SalesOffice] = [salesoffice].[salesoffice]
      left  join [IndustryCode] on [NewSalesHistory].[IndustryCode] = [IndustryCode].[IndustryCode]
      left  join [CustomerMap] on [NewSalesHistory].[ShipTo] = [CustomerMap].[SH]
      FULL join (SELECT      [Shipto]
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '6/1/2016' and '6/30/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Jun-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '7/1/2016' and '7/31/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Jul-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '8/1/2016' and '8/31/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Aug-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '9/1/2016' and '9/30/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Sep-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '10/1/2016' and '10/31/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Oct-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '11/1/2016' and '11/30/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Nov-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '12/1/2016' and '12/31/2016' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Dec-16'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '1/1/2017' and '1/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Jan-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '2/1/2017' and '2/28/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Feb-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '3/1/2017' and '3/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Mar-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '4/1/2017' and '4/30/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Apr-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '5/1/2017' and '5/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'May-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '6/1/2017' and '6/30/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Jun-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '7/1/2017' and '7/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Jul-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '8/1/2017' and '8/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Aug-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '9/1/2017' and '9/30/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Sep-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '10/1/2017' and '10/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Oct-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '11/1/2017' and '11/30/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Nov-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '12/1/2017' and '12/31/2017' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Dec-17'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '1/1/2018' and '1/31/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Jan-18'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '2/1/2018' and '2/28/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Feb-18'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '3/1/2018' and '3/31/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Mar-18'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '4/1/2018' and '4/30/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'Apr-18'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '5/1/2018' and '5/31/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as 'May-18'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '6/1/2016' and '5/31/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as '24 Month'
                ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '6/1/2017' and '5/31/2018' then ExtPrice else 0 end ) as '12 Month'
      FROM [AirgasPricing].[dbo].[BWLease]
      GROUP BY [Shipto]) X ON [NewSalesHistory].[ShipTo] = [X].[Shipto]
            where [NewSalesHistory].[Region] = 'MSO'
                and [NewSalesHistory].[PH1] not in ('LL')
                --and [NewSalesHistory].[ShipTo] = '1002996'
      GROUP BY [NewSalesHistory].[Region]
                ,[NewSalesHistory].[ShipTo]
                ,[Customer].[Name]
                ,[CustomerMap].[SP]
                ,[Customer].[SalesOffice]
                ,[SalesOffice].[City] + ' , ' + ' ' + [SalesOffice].[State]
                ,[Customer].[SalesOffice] + '-' + [SalesOffice].[City] + ' , ' + ' ' + [SalesOffice].[State]
                ,[CustomerMap].[SH-Y1]
                ,[customer].[strat1]
                ,[customer].[strat3]
                ,[salesoffice].[AVPName]
                ,[salesoffice].[DMName]
                ,SUBSTRING ([IndustryCode].[Description],1,3)
                ,[IndustryCode].[Description]
                ,[newsaleshistory].[AccountType]
                ,[X].[Jun-16]
                ,[X].[Jul-16]
                ,[X].[Aug-16]
                ,[X].[Sep-16]
                ,[X].[Oct-16]
                ,[X].[Nov-16]
                ,[X].[Dec-16]
                ,[X].[Jan-17]
                ,[X].[Feb-17]
                ,[X].[Mar-17]
                ,[X].[Apr-17]
                ,[X].[May-17]
                ,[X].[Jun-17]
                ,[X].[Jul-17]
                ,[X].[Aug-17]
                ,[X].[Sep-17]
                ,[X].[Oct-17]
                ,[X].[Nov-17]
                ,[X].[Dec-17]
                ,[X].[Jan-18]
                ,[X].[Feb-18]
                ,[X].[Mar-18]
                ,[X].[Apr-18]
                ,[X].[May-18]
                ,[X].[24 Month]
                ,[X].[12 Month]
          ORDER BY [NewSalesHistory].[Region]
                ,[NewSalesHistory].[ShipTo]
                ,[Customer].[Name]
                ,[CustomerMap].[SP]
                ,[Customer].[SalesOffice]
                ,[SalesOffice].[City] + ' , ' + ' ' + [SalesOffice].[State]
                ,[Customer].[SalesOffice] + '-' + [SalesOffice].[City] + ' , ' + ' ' + [SalesOffice].[State]
                ,[CustomerMap].[SH-Y1]
                ,[customer].[strat1]
                ,[customer].[strat3]
                ,[salesoffice].[AVPName]
                ,[salesoffice].[DMName]
                ,SUBSTRING ([IndustryCode].[Description],1,3)
                ,[IndustryCode].[Description]
                ,[newsaleshistory].[AccountType]
```

Comment: change the sub-query to a left join and move the aggregate to the select...and then remove then from the group by

Comment: This didn't seem to work, if I did or followed your syntax correctly